# Sending a Signal inside the Photon sphere

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, metric-tensor

You and a friend are inside the Photon sphere of black holes(Non rotating and uncharged).

At what angles and speed(Momentum) you need to throw a stone(or anything else )so that it reach him According to the General relativity(**schwarzschild metric)**.

(if he is on the other side with the same distance separation from the photon sphere).

Comment: Huh? Your first sentence says that both you and your friend are inside the photon sphere, but then your last sentence says the friend is on the other side?

Comment: the other side inside the photon sphere. if the black hole is the origin and you're distance from it is R then the distance from the BH to your friend is -R .But both of you are inside that sphere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question is that a physical observer can only be on time-like orbits, whereas the photon sphere is defined by null-like orbits. So you couldn't really exist on the photon sphere.

However, if you (and your friend) somehow accelerate to nearly the speed of light, it might be good enough to stay very close to the photon sphere for a finite amount of time. Then every photon you emit will essentially be going in the same direction that you are, with an enormous blueshift as seen by a stationary observer. If your friend is moving in any direction different than you, she will be vaporized by the beam.

But let's say you are both orbiting at the equator at the same speed, 180deg apart in phase, and moving at 0.999999c. From the point of view of a distant observer, it would take a million orbits for the photon to catch your friend. But from your point of view, it would happen in a single light-crossing time.